# Intercepting Sound From Other Programs

Tags: audio, driver, signal-processing, max-msp-jitter

I want to do a couple of things:

-I want to hear sound from all other programs through max, and max only.

-I want to edit that sound in real time and hear only the edited sound.

-I want to slow down the sound, while stacking the non-slowed, incoming input onto a buffer, which I can then speed through to catch up.

Is this possible in Max? I have had a lot of difficulty working even step 1. Even if I use my speakers as an input device, I am unable to monitor it let alone edit it. I am using Max for Live, for what it's worth.

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1 and 2**

On Mac, you can use [Loopback](https://rogueamoeba.com/loopback/)

You can set your system output to the loopback driver, then set the loopback driver as the input in Max and then the speakers as the output.

For Windows you would do the same, but with a different internal audio routing system like [Jack](https://jackaudio.org/faq/jack_on_windows.html)

**Step 3**

You can do that with the `buffer~` object. Of course the buffer will have a finite size, and storing hours of audio might be problematic, but minutes shouldn't be a problem on a decent computer. The `buffer~` help file will show you the first steps needed to store and read audio from it.